# Qual função PHP para abrir uma página se a condição for verdadeira?

Tags: php

Quero que quando a pessoa for fazer uma busca no formulário, se a busca for verdadeira que abra uma página existente relacionado à busca, que função posso usar para isso?

Answer (score 2):

Você define o valor da variável $busca de acordo com a condição que você quiser, e a função **header()** faz o redirecionamento.

```
<?php

if ($busca == true) {
  header("Location: pagina_busca.php");
}

?>
```

Espero ter ajudado, não deu para entender o problema com clareza.